# Clojure Loop can only recur from tail position

Tags: clojure

i want to create 500 circles but add them only when the new circle is not collide with an existing.

so here is my loop

```
  (let [total-circles 500
        circles (loop [n 0 {:keys [x y d] :as circle} (create-circle) circles ()]
                  (cond
                    (>= n total-circles) circles

                    (if (not (does-circle-have-a-collision circles circle))
                      (recur (inc n) (create-circle) (conj circles circle))
                      (recur n (create-circle) circles))

                    :else (recur (inc n) (create-circle) circles)))])
```

the error message is

Syntax error (UnsupportedOperationException) compiling recur at (sketch/dynamic.clj:82:21).
Can only recur from tail position

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

`cond` takes clauses in *pairs*, specifically `test`/`expr` pairs. That means `cond` should always have an even number of forms inside it, but yours does not. Your `(if ...)` form is sitting in the position of a `test` without a subsequent `expr`. If we abbreviate things to see the structure, it looks like this:

```clj
(cond
  ;; test    ;; expr
  (>= ...)   circles
  (if ...)   !!!missing!!!
  :else      (recur ...))
```

One way to fix that is to pull out the test from your `if` but drop the `if`, like below. (Note: I rearranged your existing logic without testing it, so not sure if this will actually work, but the structure is correct. Also I put the `test`/`expr` pairs on separate lines and indented the `expr`s so they stand out.)

```clj
(cond
  ;; test
    ;; expr
  (>= n total-circles) 
    circles
  (does-circle-have-a-collision circles circle) 
    (recur n (create-circle) circles)
  :else 
    (recur (inc n) (create-circle) (conj circles circle)))
```

In the above, calling `recur` from any `expr` clause is okay.

You're keeping track of bindings in your `loop`/`recur` that you probably don't need. For example, you don't need to track `n` when you can just check the `count` of your circles collection. Let's assume you have a function

```clj
(defn add-if-no-overlap [coll c] ...)
```

that returns `coll` with `c` added if it doesn't overlap with any circle already in `coll`, otherwise it returns `coll`. Then you could generate your 500 non-overlapping circles like so:

```clj
(defn generate-circles [total]
  (loop [circles ()]
    (if (< (count circles) total)
      (recur (add-if-no-overlap circles (create-circle)))
      circles)))

(generate-circles 500)
```

Comment: thx for your help. I'm very new to Clojure and sometimes I have no idea what's wrong. my goal is to create circles that doesn't overlap. so need to change my logic with your change of code in the first example. I have to change does-circle-have-a-collision to does-circle-have-NOT-a-collision.

Comment: I understand now what you mean by collision/overlap. I'm going to edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cond` is badly structured. The structure should be

```
(cond if1 then1
      if2 then2
      if3 then3)
```

But you have

```
(cond if1 then1
      ???mystery stuff???
      if2 then2)
```

Restructure your mystery stuff to be shaped the way that `cond` expects.

Comment: Yes this I my question. how to restructure?